# Having already made changes to the git, can I commit these changes to a new branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

If so, what is the command for that?

Thanks so much SO community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have not committed:

```
git checkout -b newbranch; git commit
```

If you have committed:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

If you have committed and not pushed and want to remove them from the old branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch; git checkout oldbranch; git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If you have committed and pushed and want to remove them from the old branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranch; git checkout oldbranch; git revert HEAD
```

I strongly recommend reading the Pro Git book.  http://progit.org

Comment: Right on! Thanks a million bazillion Seth Robertson.

Comment: Those last two could use `git branch newbranch` (create branch without switching to it) instead of `git checkout -b newbranch; git checkout oldbranch`.

Answer (score 0):

SO to the rescue [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/816614#816614)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have commited changes that you want to commit again, but on another branch. Then you are looking for **git cherry-pick**